# Magento - change item attribute value in quote just for this session

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I'm struggling with something and will appreciate your help.
In Magento 1.7:
User adding products to cart > I'm running an observer and checking some data > I want to change a product's attribute value only for that user session.

For example: user adding a T-Shirt with attribute some_text = 'example' , now I'm checking a condition and if its true, I want to change the some_text to 'other example'. But only for that user, I don't want to save it to the product itself.

I tried:

```
   foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if (some_condition) {
            $item->getProduct()->setSomeText('other example')->save();
        }
    }
```

But that **saves the attribute to the product and effecting all other users** as well.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to be using a Custom Option for this. Or maybe a Magento Configurable Products.

You can set the Custom Option to be a text field then populate it with a jQuery script when 'some data' is checked on page load or at 'add to cart' or whenever.

I do not think you will be successful updating an attribute in the way you have outlined above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but those attributes are coming from an extension I'm using. anyhow, I found a workaround. nothing worth publishing here, since it's very specific to my website.